# Replace integer entered into gets.chomp input field

Tags: ruby

So I'm completely new to Ruby. I apologize in advance.

A few lessons in on code-academy and I thought of testing the waters a bit. The code I am playing with is like so,

```
puts "Enter some text"
input_value = gets.chomp

hello_value = "whats up"

if input_value.include? "hello"
input_value.gsub! "hello", "#{hello_value}"
end

puts input_value
```

This seems to work fine. However, when I try adding a number like so,

```
puts "Enter some number"
input_value = gets.chomp

number_value = 1000

if input_value.include? "100"
input_value.gsub! "100", "#{number_value}"
end

puts input_value
```

This seems to freeze up after entering the number. I have no idea as what could be wrong. I was actually looking at ways to replace a entered value. Unfortunately, my very limited knowledge has stumped me completely lol. Any feedback on what I could do to resolve this would be appreciated.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I tested, it doesn't freeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine. Just be sure that you're inputting `100`, because that's your condition: `input_value.include? "100"`.

So, if you input

```
Hello100World
```

Your code outputs

```
Hello1000World
```

As expected, right?

Comment: Thank you for confirming this. Looks like an issue on cmd on not an issue with what I've typed then. I've been running it as admin (is that the issue?). I'll try some troubleshooting, should be up in no time.